# can not be resolved or is not a field, android error

Tags: android

I am writing an android based application, which has many activities, I want to move between them but I am getting this error:  `cannot be resolved or is not a filed`.

here is the main code:

```
    public void onButtonClicker(View v)
            {
                Intent intent;

                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.hotels_bt:
                    intent = new Intent(this, hotels.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case R.id.restaurants_bt:
                    intent = new Intent(this, restaurants.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case R.id.airports_bt:
                    intent = new Intent(this, airports.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case R.id.currency_bt:
                    intent = new Intent(this, currency.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case R.id.praytime_bt:
                    intent = new Intent(this, prayTime.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case R.id.about_bt:
                    intent = new Intent(this, about.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;  
                default:
                    break;
                }


 }
```

at each class name I am getting this error, I don't know what is the cause of it.

Comment: The first character should be a capital

Comment: @Merlin I capitalized the classes' names, the error gone, but when I run the application and press any button; the application crashes

Comment: What does the logcat say from the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure both the name of the .java file (class name) and the reference to it (Activity.class) start with a capital.

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter of `new Intent` takes a type-specific class name. so you need to make sure that if you name your files Hotels.java, that you specifically type Hotels.class and make sure Hotels is imported at the top of your activity.

Comment: you shouldn't need to import them